# Binding data to a dropdown using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a typescript controller with an init method below. I am able to get all the data I want in the messageresult
which is good.

```
         init() {   
                     this.accountLocationService.getAccountLocationCollection(this.customerNumber)
                        .success(messageresult => {
                            this.acctLocationCollection = messageresult;                                    
                            //alert(this.acctLocationCollection.accountlocation[0].aliasName);
                        })
                        .error(error => {
                            alert(error);
                        });
                }
```

The acctLocationCollection can have two or more  objects and I need to bind all the values of the
aliasName in a dropdown below. 
How can I achive this ? This is my first AngularJs project.

```
        <div id="acctDetail">
            <p>Select an Account:</p>
            <div class="selectAccount">
                <select class="selAccounts" name="DeliverToCustomerNumber" ng-change="" id="DeliverToCustomerNumber" 
                        ng-options="ac for ac in alc.acctLocationCollection.aliasName">         
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="address">
                <dl>
                    <dd class="acctName">{{alc.acctLocationCollection.DeliverToCompanyName}}</dd>
                    <dd class="acctNo">{{alc.acctLocationCollection.DeliverToCustomerNumber}}</dd>           
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Data looks like this in console.log

```
    object 
    accountlocation:Array[2]
    0:object
      aliasName:"1234"
      deliverToCustomerNumber: "25235"

    1:object
      aliasName:"2345"
      deliverToCustomerNumber: "23523"
```

Comment: Just a note -- since you're using TypeScript, you don't need an `init()` function. You can simply use the TypeScript constructor. (Unless you're already calling `init()` from your constructor) :)

Comment: @BenBeck Even better, as of Angular 1.5.x you can use `$onInit() {}` withTypeScript and then you don't even have to call it from your constructor. It will fire automatically when the module is instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an `ng-model` on your select so I will just assume you want to store the object from your `acctLocationCollection`. To do this you simply need to structure your `ng-options` as follows:

```
<select class="selAccounts" 
        name="DeliverToCustomerNumber" 
        id="DeliverToCustomerNumber" 
        ng-model="alc.selectedAcctLocation"
        ng-options="ac as ac.aliasName for ac in alc.acctLocationCollection">
</select>
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.selectedAcctLocation = {};
    this.acctLocation = [{
      aliasName: "1234",
      deliverToCustomerNumber: "25235"
    }, {
      aliasName: "2345",
      deliverToCustomerNumber: "23523"
    }];
    console.log(this.acctLocation);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as alc">
  By object: <select ng-model="alc.selectedAcctLocation" ng-options="ac as ac.aliasName for ac in alc.acctLocation"></select><br/>
  By (key,value): <select ng-model="alc.selectedAcctLocation" ng-options="value as value.aliasName for (key,value) in alc.acctLocation"></select>
  <div style="margin-top:10px;">
    alc.acctLocation:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in alc.acctLocation">{{key}}: {{value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>selectedAcctLocation: {{alc.selectedAcctLocation | json}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this now. Do I need the ng-model?

Comment: That is how you store the value selected by the user, but yes - without it Angular won't render your options.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code above and nothing was displayed in the dropdown. It is still empty.

Comment: Can you ammend your question with the full output of `console.log(messageresult)` from your `init()` method? Without seeing the structure of the data being returned it's very hard to troubleshoot what might be occurring.

Comment: I updated the `ng-model` attribute as I had forgotten to include the controller prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139606/discussion-between-user2320476-and-lex).